# Facebook integration error in ios xcode 9.1

Tags: xcode4

App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key `FacebookAppID` to the Info.plist or call `[FBSDKSettings setAppID:]`.'

> facebook integration error

showing this error when i click on facebook login button in my app